# Error when sending multiple values for a dimension in SSRS through JSON

Tags: web, reporting-services, olap-cube

- I have a problem in the syntax that I have to send in my JSON so that my SSRS can read it I work with cubes this is the JSON that I send:
  [
  {"name": "code1", "valor":"[date].[year].[2023],[date].[year].[2024]"}, {"name": "code", "value":"[date].[month].[All]"}
  ] The problem gives me when I send more than one value similar to this  "[date].[year].[2023],[date].[year].[2024]" but when I send only one there is no problem. Please help me.